# Linker error on iOS cocos2d-x hybrid project

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a hybrid Cocos2d-X project for iOS & Android. I can build the iOS project using command line but the Xcode gives me linker error.

Although it builds successfully & clean as well as I am able to export the archive as well from command line. Xcode says 176 errors. That number looks overwhelming though. 
Any help, I am sure there is some small thing that is missing from the Xcode lining and is linked using the command line.

Comment: what cocos2d-x version? How did you make this project?

Comment: The project is actually a visual studio cocos-2d based project.
Later the platform iOS and Android was added to it. The version of VisualStudio was 7.0 and cocos2d-x is 3.8.1 as per the cocos2d.cpp from C++ function coco2dVersion().

I have all the distribution provisioning profiles and certificate to create the build. I can create it from Terminal but from Xcode it gives me linker error.